# Facebook like button is not linked with the like in the fan page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-page

For example, I have an article in my site,

http://abc.com/1.html

and I put a like button plugin from Facebook in the website  for this article (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like)

And I also have a fan page in Facebook and share this article (by sharing a link).

If I press the link button in my site, the fan page like for this article does not add up. And vice versa, if I click the like button of this article in fan page, it does not reflect on the website either.

So is it the default behavior? I thought the article URL is provided for the Facebook Like plugin, the info should be linked. Anything I am missing here?

Thanks.

Comment: I guess on Facebook the users are liking the "feed" story itself and **not** the link. Try it with mashable, go for any mashable article (that you didn't Like yet), share it on Facebook and go back to the article, you'll find that you don't "like" it.

Answer (score 2):

When you put an Like Button on your website for this particular article,
it's usually linked to an "Open Graph FaceBook Page", not your regular Facebook Fan Page, with a wall page. Open Graph FaceBook Page will redirect users to your own website. The good part of it, is that you'll be able to post news in the fans news feed.

When you share that article on your Fan Page, fans would LIKE the news feed post, not your website's article.

You can link the like buttons to your Fan Page, but you'll loose specific article liking capabilities.
As described in the doc (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like) :

> **Can I link the Like button to my Facebook page?**
>   Yes. Simply specify the URL of your Facebook page in the href parameter of the button.

Answer (score 1):

The first like is for your site, the second like is for the feed story -- they are two distinct objects.